# ¿"Hojear" u "ojear" las páginas de un libro?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos

[Hojear](https://dle.rae.es/hojear) tiene, entre otras, las siguientes acepciones:

> 1. tr. Mover o pasar ligeramente las hojas de un libro o de un cuaderno.
> 2. tr. Pasar las hojas de un libro, leyendo deprisa algunos pasajes.

mientras que [ojear<sup>1</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/ojear) es:

> 3. tr. Lanzar ojeadas a algo.
> 4. tr. Mirar superficialmente un texto.

Para describir la acción de pasar rápidamente las páginas de un libro, mirando brevemente su contenido, ¿cuál de los dos verbos es el más adecuado?

Comment: El problema inverso también es curioso. Si te dicen (fonéticamente) que Ana está "hojeando/ojeando" tu libro. ¿Qué se entiende? ¿Que está pasando rápidamente sus hojas o que mira superficialmente su contenido?

Answer (score 3):

Para *pasar rápidamente las páginas* se usa *hojear* con *h*, como bien explica el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:

> [**hojear**](https://www.rae.es/dpd/hojear). ‘Pasar rápidamente las páginas [de una publicación, libro o cuaderno] sin leerlas detenidamente’: *«Un día cogí el libro de firmas del velatorio de mi marido y me puse a hojearlo»* (Millás Mujeres [Esp. 2002]). No debe confundirse con ojear (‘echar una mirada rápida y superficial’; → ojear).

Answer (score 2):

A ver si lo siguiente funciona: Cuando Hojeas un libro, lo que haces es pasar rápido sus hojas, y cada hoja la Ojeas (hay muy pocos casos en que una persona hojee un libro sin ojear cada una de sus páginas).

Answer (score 0):

En las deficiones que pones en tu pregunta está la respuesta:

> Para describir la acción de pasar rápidamente las páginas de un libro
> **-> Hojear**
>
> Mirando brevemente su contenido **-> Ojear**